# Get the latest record in the table on a given day

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table with columns `offer_id`, `item_id` and `report_date`(*not timestamp, just date*)

I want to get the *latest* record of `offer_id` for a *particular* `item_id` on that given date .

Can anyone help?

I tried something like below, but not sure if its right, still learning :

```
SELECT A.report_dt, A.offer_id, A.item_id
  FROM table A
 WHERE A.rpt_dt = (SELECT MAX(rpt_dt)
                     FROM table
                    WHERE item_id = A.item_id
                      AND report_dt = date'2020-06-01')
 ORDER BY item_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the latest `offer_id` values for each particular `item_id` by using [Window Functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) such as `RANK()` as below :

```
SELECT offer_id, item_id
  FROM
  (
   SELECT t.*,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id
                      ORDER BY report_dt DESC) AS rnk
     FROM tab t
  ) tt  
 WHERE tt.rnk = 1
```

where `report_dt` values are ordered descendingly(`ORDER BY report_dt DESC`) for each grouped `item_id`(`PARTITION BY item_id`) within the subquery.